# How to add a new a new data provider to the react-documentation?

Tags: react-admin

I created a new data provider for Strapi.js [ra-strapi-rest](https://github.com/nazirov91/ra-strapi-rest). How do I add it to the react-admin documentation page?

Comment: Ask the maintainers, via GitHub.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a special section in [Contributing](https://marmelab.com/react-admin/index.html#contributing) on the Documentation page that describes how to submit a pull request for documentation updates.